# How to specify java compiler option in IntelliJ and Ant

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea, javac

I want to generate debug information from my source code in IntelliJ.

I can use this in command line:

```
javac -g
```

But how could I do that in IntelliJ and Ant? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IDEA enable `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Java Compiler`, **Generate debugging info**. When using Ant add `debug="true"` to `<javac>` task.